# Even number from parent loop skipped on i == j, in python

Tags: python

I want to find list `l1` is subset of list `l2`

I have the code below:

```py
def subset(l1, l2):
    if len(l1) <= len(l2):
        for i in l1:
            for j in l2:
                if l1 == l2:
                    l1.remove(i)
        if not l1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False


print(subset([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

The problem the condition does not work `i == j` causes a problem.

```py
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in l1:
    for j in l2:
        if i == j:
            print(i, j)
            print(True)
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand your english here, is this code causing an error or is it just not returning the result you're expecting?

Comment: modifying a list while iterating on it is a very bad idea since results can be unpredictable. Instead of removing duplicates from `l1`, you should build a new list without the duplicates.

Comment: @CapnJack look to last part of code, this is not working as i expected, i printing the i and j value, the loop iterate only on odd value for i!!!!!

Comment: @Tryph Consider the last part of my question, the for i loop only iterate on odd value!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @MuhamamdUmerFarooq If I run the code of the last part of your question, the result is what I expected: a list of duplicates: `1 1`, `2 2`, `3 3`.

Comment: @Selcuk no no, am not calling function, i just trying what the error you may see from my last part look here https://onlinegdb.com/ryy_XIfoB

Comment: @Tryph See here https://onlinegdb.com/rk-mNIzir

Comment: @MuhamamdUmerFarooq Your last example doesn't work because it modifies the `l1` list (`l1.remove(...)` line) while iterating on, which is a very bad idea as I said in my first comment. The previously posted example on onlinegdb works perfectly, you should try it. Also see https://onlinegdb.com/SkusrIGiH

Comment: @Tryph it now work, you can see, the function return [2] , but it should return True, which mean the loop cant iterate over even number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
total = 0
for i in range(0, len(l1)):
   value = l1[i]
   for j in range(0, len(l2)):
      if l2[j] == value:
         total +=1

if total == len(l1):
   print("list is subset")
else:
   print("list is not subset")
```

Comment: Just move he logic into your method.

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: I did but i have less " reputation" point, so its not appear public

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem of subset just simplifying the code:

```
def subset(l1, l2):
    if len(l1) > len(l2):
        return False
    for i in l1:
        if i not in l2:
            return False
    return True
```